# How to export pptx to image (png, jpeg) in Python?

Tags: python, python-pptx

I have developed a small code in Python to generate a PPTX file. But I would like also to generate a picture in PNG or JPEG of the slide.

```py
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches

img_path = 'monty-truth.png'

prs = Presentation()
blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(blank_slide_layout)

left = top = Inches(1)
pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(img_path, left, top)

left = Inches(5)
height = Inches(5.5)
pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(img_path, left, top, height=height)

prs.save('test.pptx')
```

Is there a way to transform a PPTX file (including just one slide) into a PNG or JPEG picture ?

Comment: No. And it's unlikely it ever will. Doing this would require a rendering engine, something outside the scope of python-pptx's vision. Only way I've heard of folks doing this is by using the win32 API on Windows to have the built-in PowerPoint application save as images and work from there. I've heard talk about folks doing something similar with the OpenOffice library but don't know anything more about that.

Comment: I think maybe converting the pptx file  into a pdf and then turning it into  image(s) will be the best approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code :

```
Application = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
Presentation = Application.Presentations.Open(r"your_path")
Presentation.Slides[0].Export(r"the_new_path-file.jpg", "JPG")
Application.Quit()
Presentation =  None
Application = None
```

With this line, you can change the number of the slide you want to export (for example below, for slide number 6) :

```
Presentation.Slides[5].Export(r"the_new_path-file.jpg", "JPG")
```

Comment: That's on Windows. With Mac it would have to be AppleScript.

Comment: I got the below while exporting to JPG.

File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in Export                                                                       pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft PowerPoint', "Slide.Export : PowerPoint can't save ^0 to ^1.", '', 0, -2147467259), None)

Comment: its not python code. how to run this code? is it shell script or what?

Answer (score 1):

As a detour, you can first convert PPT to PDF, and then convert PDF to images. To convert PPT to PDF, you can use libreoffice:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf test.pptx
```

To convert PDF to image, you can use [poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/).

```
pdftoppm -singlefile -f 4 -r 72 -jpeg -jpegopt quality=90 test.pdf test_poppler
```

This is also a python package [pdf2image](https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image) which is basically a wrapper around poppler. You may also be interested in it.

For more info: see [convert ppt slide to image](https://jdhao.github.io/2020/03/30/pptx_to_image/) and [Converting PDF Pages to Images with Poppler](https://jdhao.github.io/2019/11/14/convert_pdf_to_images_pdftoppm/).

Answer (score 0):

There's a python package called Aspose.Slides which could convert pptx to png.

Do:

```
pip install Aspose.Slides
```

This can also be used for converting pptx to pdf, as well as for creating a pptx file from scratch.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. E.g. on how to use that package in the OPs case. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Aspose is not a good alternative as it adds watermark over the generated images

Answer (score 0):

My solution basically uses the win32com library. If you have not installed that library the install it using pip.
Lets just skip the explanation and get into the code.!! Heads up, another pre-requisite is that u need the ppt to be saved somewhere already.
code:

```
import win32com.client
import os

# Specify the full path to the PowerPoint presentation
presentation_path = r"The path to your presentation"

# Create a PowerPoint application object
Application = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
def ppt_to_png():
    try:
        # Open the presentation without making it visible
        Presentation = Application.Presentations.Open(presentation_path, WithWindow=False)

        # Create a folder to save the slides as images
        slides_folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(presentation_path), "Slides")
        if not os.path.exists(slides_folder):
            os.makedirs(slides_folder)

        # Export each slide as an image
        for i, slide in enumerate(Presentation.Slides):
            image_path = os.path.join(slides_folder, f"{i + 1}.png")
            slide.Export(image_path, "JPG")

        # Close the presentation
        Presentation.Close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    finally:
        # Quit the PowerPoint application
        Application.Quit()
```

**Remember to call the function where required**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).