# How to export ppt slide as image using pptx python

Tags: python, python-pptx

I want to export a ppt slide as an png format image through pptx python.

I have gone through this solution [using win32com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61815883/python-pptx-export-img-png-jpeg) but facing error as `com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)` while running `win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")`

I have also tried using `pptx_tools.utils.save_pptx_as_png`, but it is asking `Comptype module needed to save PNGs.` and I don't find any `comptype` module in Python. I have installed `comtype` module but it is throwing an syntax error while importing.

Please let me know any efficient way to export pptx slide as image

Answer (score 0):

As you've tagged this with "python-pptx" I have to tell you python-pptx can't do it.

You'd have to do it by automating the Powerpoint application itself. (Sorry, I don't know how to do that.)

Answer (score 0):

After I try many times, I corrected some places and it runs fine:

1. Import module:
   `import win32com.client`
2. Your path 1 (pptx file):
   "/ddd/xxx/yyy/file.pptx"
3. Your path 2 (output file):
   "/ddd/xxx/yyy/file.jpg"